# Exception cannot be converted to Throwable

Tags: java, exception

I'm working on macOS with JDK8.

In catch, I have to give the entire name of exception like
in this case (ArithmeticException e) instead of (Exception e)
to run the code.

If I use (Exception e) it gives an error that I'm not getting on windows os.

why is that??
and how should I solve this??

The code works perfectly on windows OS with JDK8.
On macOS work perfectly if the proper name of the exception (ArithmeticException e) is given.

```
import java.util.*;
public class ExceptionDemo
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
   int a,b,c;
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("enter first number:");
   a=sc.nextInt();
   System.out.println("enter second number:");
   b=sc.nextInt();
   try
   {
       c=a/b;
       System.out.println("Result is:"+c);
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       System.out.println("second number cannot be zero/0 "+e);
   }

   System.out.println("still running");
   }
   }
```

This is the error I'm getting as below:

> incompatible types: Exception cannot be converted to Throwable
>     catch(Exception e)

Comment: You probably created your own Exception class that isn't actually a Throwable, and which hides the standard java.lang.Exception class. Delete this class.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to java and I didn't get what u suggested. I uploaded the entire code this time so plz explain in little detail.

Comment: I suggest that you created a class, and you named it Exception. And so, this class of yours has the same name as the standard Exception class provided by Java, and that name clash causes the problem you're seeing. And I thus suggest to delete that class that you named Exception (or at least rename it to something else), to avoid this name clash.

Comment: I renamed class to Demoe, but still getting the same error.

Comment: You're not reading carefully. The class you posted doesn't need to be renamed. What needs to be renamed is the **other** class that, I guess, you created and named `Exception`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
catch(java.lang.Exception e) {
    // handle e
}
```

Use fully-qualified names if you aren't sure what is imported, and what class will be used under the name `Exception`.

The name `Exception` looks too broad for your application. `[YourApplicationName]Exception` would be a cleaner and conflictless root of your exception hierarchy (if you want to have one).

Comment: It works. but why I have to use java.lang.Exception. and why (Exception e)giving error on macOS but not on windows??

Comment: @SiddheshJadhav  JB Nizet did a great job explaining it in the comments. There is another `Exception` you imported explicitly or implicitly (if it is in the same package with `ExceptionDemo`) and used, which isn't a subclass of `Exception` and, thus, can't be used in a `catch` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, but later I noticed that my class name was Exception because of my class name which is(Exception ) I was getting that error .when I changed my class name (filename )  then it work.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any file named "Exception.java" then rename that file and delete that class file then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your file name is `Exception.java` and the class you are trying to implement is the same, but from a different package (java.lang.Exception), so either you change your file name, or you can import that package, or you can write the full package at the catch param block.

Answer (score -5):

you should import first

```
import java.lang.Exception;
```

Comment: Please Brief  your answer